# Hyperlinks in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a button in Excel which links to:

> http://datafeed.api.productserve.com/datafeed/download/apikey/50f70c7de11f99fe127d7ad4c8e37e31/cid/97,98,142,144,
>   ...
>   ,567,569/fid/4319/columns/merchant_product_id,merchant_category,brand_name,product_name,mpn,search_price,aw_deep_link,specifications,valid_from,valid_to,in_stock,warranty,aw_product_id,merchant_image_url,description/format/csv/delimiter/,/compression/gzip/adultcontent/1/

I've cut out a large section in the middle, but it is just a long sequence of numbers separated by commas. In total the URL is 1939 characters long.

Copying the URL into a browser works fine - it is a download link and the file opens as it should.

The code for the button is simple:

```
Private Sub download_button_Click()

Dim feed_hyperlink As String
feed_hyperlink = *"http://data...  "*

ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink feed_hyperlink

End Sub
```

When I run the procedure, I get the following error:

> Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

Hyperlinking a cell restricts the destination URL to 255 characters. Is a character limit what's causing the issue here, or is there another problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right. It's probably too long as the longest one I can use before getting the same error is `1033` characters;

```
Sub Main()

    Dim h As String
    h = String(1034, "a")

    Debug.Print Len(h)

    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink h

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.

I tried using a URL shortener to get round the problem, but it's not working... Have to find a way to work around it.

Comment: maybe create an URL mask - so like `http://localhost` and have the localhost redirect to the correct url? idk just an idea